# Unable to CREATE PRIMARY INDEX for couchbase bucket. on UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: php, laravel-4, ubuntu-14.04, couchbase

I am trying to get data from couchbase bucket using laravel 4.2 . And facing issue related to PRIMARY INDEX. Below are the details. Can someone please suggest where I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Controller:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use CouchbaseCluster;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function index() {


//        phpinfo();die;

//        
    $Cluster  =  New  CouchbaseCluster ( 'http://127.0.0.1:8091' ); 
    $Bucket = $Cluster->OpenBucket('beer-sample');

// Retrieve a document

    Try {
        $Result = $Bucket->Get('21St_amendment_brewery_cafe');
    } Catch (Exception $E) {
        Echo "CouchbaseException:" . $E->getMessage() . " \ N ";
    }
    $doc = Json_decode($Result->Value, True);
    var_dump($doc);die;
    }

}
```

getting below error message:

```html
CouchbaseException in CouchbaseBucket.class.php line 196:
The key does not exist on the server
```

Then I changed my controller code and ran it again.

Controller(Updated):

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use CouchbaseCluster;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function index() {


//        phpinfo();die;
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM `beer-sample` limit 2';
        $res = \DB::connection()->bucket('beer-sample')->select($query);
        var_dump($res);die;

    }

}
```

Then I am getting this error.

```html
QueryException in Connection.php line 673:
No primary index on keyspace beer-sample. Use CREATE PRIMARY INDEX to create one. (SQL: SELECT * FROM `beer-sample` limit 2)
```

It seems both errors are related to (PRIMARY) Key. So, I tried to create primary key from my controller and ./cbq . But cases are failing. Below are the details.

Controller logic to create PRIMARY KEY:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use CouchbaseCluster;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function index() {


//        phpinfo();die;
        $query = 'CREATE PRIMARY INDEX `beer-sample-primary-index` ON `beer-sample` USING GSI WITH {"defer_build":true};';
        $res = \DB::connection()->bucket('beer-sample')->select($query);
        var_dump($res);die;      
  }

}
```

Page is throwing below error:

```html
QueryException in Connection.php line 673:
GSI CreatePrimaryIndex() - cause: Fails to create index. There is no available index service that can process this request at this time. Index Service can be in bootstrap, recovery, or non-reachable. Please retry the operation at a later time. (SQL: CREATE PRIMARY INDEX `beer-sample-primary-index` ON `beer-sample` USING GSI WITH {"defer_build":true};)
```

Query from ./cbq also thrown similar error.

```html
srturaka@srturaka-pc:/opt/couchbase/bin$ ./cbq
Couchbase query shell connected to http://localhost:8093/ . Type Ctrl-D to exit.
cbq> CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON `beer-sample` USING GSI;
{
    "requestID": "30239420-7dc2-4892-ba90-1ecf0474ba19",
    "signature": null,
    "results": [
    ],
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 5000,
            "msg": "GSI CreatePrimaryIndex() - cause: Fails to create index.  There is no available index service that can process this request at this time. Index Service can be in bootstrap, recovery, or non-reachable. Please retry the operation at a later time."
        }
    ],
    "status": "errors",
    "metrics": {
        "elapsedTime": "10.005267815s",
        "executionTime": "10.005169082s",
        "resultCount": 0,
        "resultSize": 0,
        "errorCount": 1
    }
}
```

Please help me on how to create PRIMARY KEY for couchbase buckets. Let me know if more information is required.

**EDIT**

[image]

**Server Node Screenshots**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you check in the nodes tab of the webconsole that you have at least one node with the `index` service. on a typical dev local installation, you'd have a single node with the 3 services: `data`, `index` and `query`... Also, which couchbase server version are you using?

Comment: I have added Server nodes screen shots in my question. Not sure how to check if Index service is available.Can you pls see if you get some clue from screen shots.  I am using couchbase server 4.0.0.

Comment: Index seems activated, as indicated in the second screenshot, right of the "up" green sign. But the index service is apparently failing... Maybe you can get someone from support to help you diagnose if you post in the Couchbase Forums

Comment: Have you tried running the "CREATE INDEX..." directly on the Couchbase Console? Click on the "Query" tab to do so. But from your screenshots, it looks like there isn't a query tab, so maybe you are using an older version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a proper way, but my issue got resolved after I changed my query to below.And I am able to perform CRUD operations.

```
$query = 'CREATE PRIMARY INDEX `beer-sample-primary-index` ON `beer-sample` USING View';
```

"*VIEW instead of GSI;*"

Answer (score -1):

For me bucket name with '-' doesnt work while creating index. So beer-sample doesnt work but beer_sample works.

Comment: names with '-' needs to be quoted with backticks i.e. \`beer-sample\`

Comment: This does not answer the question, nor is it correct.